# DatePickerFragment SelectedValue Xamarin.Android

Tags: xamarin.android, datepicker

I want to pick a date in a DatePickerFragment in xamarin android like this:

```
DatePickerFragment frag = DatePickerFragment.NewInstance(delegate(DateTime time)
            {
                LoadMap(time.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));

            });

            frag.Show(FragmentManager, DatePickerFragment.TAG);
```

Meanwhile the DatePickerFragment Class is like this:

```
 public class DatePickerFragment : Android.Support.V4.App.DialogFragment,
                              DatePickerDialog.IOnDateSetListener
{
    // TAG can be any string of your choice.
    public static readonly string TAG = "X:" + typeof(DatePickerFragment).Name.ToUpper();

    // Initialize this value to prevent NullReferenceExceptions.
    Action<DateTime> _dateSelectedHandler = delegate { };

    public static DatePickerFragment NewInstance(Action<DateTime> onDateSelected)
    {
        DatePickerFragment frag = new DatePickerFragment();
        frag._dateSelectedHandler = onDateSelected;
        return frag;
    }

    public override Dialog OnCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        DateTime currently = DateTime.Now;
        DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(Activity,
                                                       this,
                                                       currently.Year,
                                                       currently.Month - 1,
                                                       currently.Day);
        return dialog;
    }

    public void OnDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
    {
        // Note: monthOfYear is a value between 0 and 11, not 1 and 12!
        DateTime selectedDate = new DateTime(year, monthOfYear + 1, dayOfMonth);
        Log.Debug(TAG, selectedDate.ToLongDateString());
        _dateSelectedHandler(selectedDate);
    }
}
```

The problem is that everytime i try to pick a date, the datepicker shows only today, it happens cause of `DateTime currently = DateTime.Now;`. How can I change this, so the Datepicker stores the last selected date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved by declaring `static selectedDate = DateTime.Today;` in the `DatePickerFragment` Class, full class below:

```
public class DatePickerFragment : Android.Support.V4.App.DialogFragment, DatePickerDialog.IOnDateSetListener
{
    // TAG can be any string of your choice.
    public static readonly string TAG = "X:" + typeof(DatePickerFragment).Name.ToUpper();

    // Initialize this value to prevent NullReferenceExceptions.
    Action<DateTime> _dateSelectedHandler = delegate { };

    private static DateTime selectedDate = DateTime.Today;

    public static DatePickerFragment NewInstance(Action<DateTime> onDateSelected)
    {
        DatePickerFragment frag = new DatePickerFragment();
        frag._dateSelectedHandler = onDateSelected;
        return frag;
    }

    public override Dialog OnCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        DateTime currently = selectedDate;

        DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(Activity,
                                                       this,
                                                       currently.Year,
                                                       currently.Month - 1,
                                                       currently.Day);
        return dialog;
    }

    public void OnDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
    {
        // Note: monthOfYear is a value between 0 and 11, not 1 and 12!
        selectedDate = new DateTime(year, monthOfYear + 1, dayOfMonth);
        Log.Debug(TAG, selectedDate.ToLongDateString());
        _dateSelectedHandler(selectedDate);
    }
}
```